# For-loop with increment by 1

Tags: r

I have this function, which declares a subtraction from column one of the entire df.

```
f_minus <- function(first_col, other_col) {
  
  other_col - first_col
  
}
```

df_ouput creates a new df with a  suitable dimension

This for-loop subtracts the column 1 from the entire df.
And I need a for-loop (not an apply, lapply etc. function) which does it not only for column 1 but also for column 2,3,4 etc. until the last column of the df. Any ideas how to approach this?

```
df_output <- as.data.frame(matrix(ncol=ncol(dfn), nrow=nrow(dfn)))

for (i in 1:ncol(dfn)) {
  
  df_output[,i] <- f_minus(dfn[,1], dfn[,i])
  
} 
  
df_output
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is just a subtraction, i dont think you need to define it, you can substitute it with the `-` operator.

```
for (i in 1:ncol(df)){
for (j in 1:ncol(df)){
df[,j]<-df[,j] - df[,i]
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice :-). But it doesn't approach the problem. Do you have an idea how I can increment df[,1] after each run by 1?

Comment: Maybe OP means that in a second iteration of an implied outer loop, it is column 2 that is subtracted from every other column in the df, then column 3, and so on..  I'm curious to know why a solution based on `apply` is unacceptable.

Comment: If I let it run through my df, it just subtract column 1 from each column. Do I miss something?

Comment: you need nested loops. Wait a couple minutes for an answer please

Comment: Because the df is too big and the error message occurs: can not allocate. @GuedesBF Take your time, sry doesn't want to hurry! Thank you for your help !!!!!